# status": 500, "body": "HTTP Error 400: Invalid URI: isHexDigit" while downloading image on s3 to local using skimage

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, boto3

My task is to upload a file to s3 bucket (public) using random urls every time. For this, I am generating urls using the below code

```
image_path = FOLDER+'/'+str(random.randint(0, 1000000))  + str(random.randint(0, 1000000))  + str(random.randint(0, 1000000)) + '%' + str(today.day) + '-' + str(today.month) + '-' + str(today.year)+'.'+extension

s3.put_object(
        Bucket=BUCKET,
        Key = image_path,
        Body = buffer,
        ContentType = 'image/'+extension,
        ACL = 'public-read'

    )
object_url = "https://s3-{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(
        REGION,
        BUCKET,
        image_path)
 from skimage import io
 image = io.imread(object_url)
```

The upload shows no error. Though now when I am trying to access the url using my browser, it shows HTTP 400. When I tried to download the same using skimage, it shows 
**status": 500, "body": "HTTP Error 400: Invalid URI: isHexDigit"**
Here: **extension**: image_extension, **today**: date object, BUCKET: s3 bucket, **buffer**: Image-object, **REGION**: s3 bucket location
A sample url is attached below: https://s3-REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/FOLDER/932724r8477P9577%4-4-2020.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your generated URL is not valid. Percent characters are reserved for [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

The following is a stripped down example that will reproduce your error; `imread()` calls `urllib.request.urlopen()` internally, and the exception originates within that call:

```py
import urllib

REGION = 'us-east-1'
BUCKET = 'BUCKET'
image_path = 'FOLDER/932724r8477P9577%4-4-2020.jpeg'

object_url = "https://s3.{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(
        REGION,
        BUCKET,
        image_path)

f = urllib.request.urlopen(object_url)
```

The above will fail with:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Invalid URI: isHexDigit
```

You need need to do percent encoding like this:

```py
import urllib

REGION = 'us-east-1'
BUCKET = 'BUCKET'
image_path = 'FOLDER/932724r8477P9577%4-4-2020.jpeg'

object_url = "https://s3.{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}/{2}".format(
        REGION,
        BUCKET,
        urllib.parse.quote(image_path))

f = urllib.request.urlopen(object_url)
```

The resulting URL will be properly encoded:

```
https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKET/FOLDER/932724r8477P9577%254-4-2020.jpeg
```